# AWSMobileClientError Sign In Screen can't be showed due to AWSAuthUI Dependency Error

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, google-signin, aws-sdk-ios

I'm trying to connect my apps to google sign in using AWS. But, the sign in screen can't be showed because AWS keep producing error like
this :

> AWSAuthUI dependency is required to show the signIn screen. Please import the dependency before using this API

my code to show signin screen:
`AWSMobileClient.default().showSignIn(navigationController: self.navigationController!,)`

pods:

[image]

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled here with the same error, but I'm not using CocoaPods. I'm using Carthage. However, I also have the following line at the top of my file:

`import AWSAuthUI`

You could try adding that, which is what the error message suggests. Now, why I'm getting the error, I don't know. I guess I'm off to do some more searching...